# Evaluation of the if condition in c as true or false

Tags: c, if-statement

```
int n,i;

scanf("%d",&n);

if(n==0)
printf("a");

else if (!(n>=1))
printf("b");
```

When I give the input as m, the condition (n==0) is evaluating to be true. When the condition is a valid expression and non-zero, then it's true. When I am replacing n by i and providing the same input, the condition n==0 is getting evaluated as false. Why is this happening?. Why is it evaluating to be true even when there's 0 in n==0 ?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf`. The value stored in `n` is not valid unless `scanf` returns success which is a return value of `1` in this case.

Comment: You have to initialize `n` like `int n = 0;`. Otherwise its value is random (nonzero).

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour*. The `int n` has not been initialised, and `scanf()` has not set any value. What is `true` today is `false` tomorrow.

Comment: *"even when there's 0 in n==0"* - says who ? You certainly didn't. Due to how they are declared (with no initialization) both `n` and `i` are *indeterminate* until explicitly assigned a value (such as a successful population from `scanf`, which you should verify).

Answer (score -1):

The definition of `scanf()` says nothing about what it will do to the value of arguments that cannot be assigned, but invariably in practice, it leaves them untouched.

In this case both `n` and `i` are unitialised and may contain any value - in your case `n` happened to contain zero at the moment you tried it, but that is not a given - it is *undefined*.  The C runtime is not required to initialise variables with `auto` storage class (local, non-`static`) to  zero.

```
int n = 0; 
int i = 0;
```

Note also that `sscanf()` returns the number of format specifiers that result in a successful assignment, so you can for example:

```
while( scanf("%d",&n) == 0 )
{
    // wait until valid input
}
```

This is strictly safer than relying only initialisation of a "default" value because `scanf()` strictly makes no guarantees that it will not modify an argument in any case - it would only be an unusual implementation that did so.  Also in practice you would normally want to handle erroneous input one way or another rather then simply ignore it and use a default.  A safe and unambiguous way of providing a default if required is:

```
if( scanf("%d",&n) == 0 )
{
    n = 0 ;
}
```